# A little clarification needed with GNU GPL v3

Tags: licensing, gpl

I'm programmaing a visual novel which has the following parts:

- Script file
- Program code used for the events where parts of the scripts are displayed
- 2 different minigames
- Images

Now one of the minigames is based on a open source code that uses the GPL v3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt

I copy pasted parts of the code for that one minigame and rewrote parts of it so that it works with my code base.

So what I understand is that I need to make the minigame itself that is based upon the open source code open source itself.

What I'm not 100% sure about is: The scriptfile and the program parts that are not directly involved with the one minigame (aside from initializing it and starting it), the second minigame and the images: Do these all also have to be open source?

*Note: A bit of explanation what the scriptfile is and a bit in regards to the open source minigame.*

*The script file is in essence a number of labels where scriptcode happens like "CharacterA with pose B says 'I'm not going to do this, no chance in hell!'".*

*The open source minigame: Depending on situations in the minigame specific events are triggered which then switch out of the minigame and onto displaying the script.*

Comment: In order to answer this, it is important how tightly coupled your program is with the GPL'd component. It is not clear to me from your description how tight that coupling is. Clear examples are: (1) a separate binary launched as a subprocess: no requirement or (2) a statically linked library: must use GPL for the whole program.

Comment: The whole program is made with renpy (a visual novel engine made via python). When I distribute the game it is compiled into rpyc files with each file that existed as source existing as rpyc file. Thus I think it would fall under statically linked library (especially as I directly call the minigame as normal command as its linked into the parts where I call it).

Comment: Maybe. In any case, using GPL3 for your whole project is a safe option. Which of course raises a question: Why not simply do it? The GPL3 is a very good license anyway, so why not use it for your code as well?

Comment: Because I'm not sure if it would encompass also the scripts themselves and the images. MOST things like the minigames I plan on releasing anyway as open source, but the images and script are not something I would like to be useable by anyone without explicit permission by me

Comment: The situation with the images is pretty clear: They need not be GPL'ed as long as it is reasonably simple to replace them. If this is your main question, I can post an answer on that.

Comment: so images would not have to be open source, but the whole source code of the program would have to be open source including the script files? (if that is so then yes that is an answer to my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data processed by your application need not be licensed under the same terms as the software itself.

To decide whether something is data or program, think whether it could be replaced by any other file (using the same file format) and your application would still work. For example, if your application uses a logo icon, you can replace it with any other picture and your application will use it just as happily (I hope). This is important because logos often contain trademarks or other features that prohibit licensing them under the GPL. If the pixels of the picture somehow encode some action performed by the program, then it is probably more than just data because replacing it by some other picture would be difficult.

A requirement is, however, that you make it reasonably simple to replace the data. If your program reads ordinary files from a directory, this is fine. Anybody can replace the files therein. If you embed the binary data of the files into the source code as a huge array of integers, it is not.

There is also a remark on the question of pictures shipped with games in the [Free System Distribution Guidelines](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-system-distribution-guidelines.en.html).

> **Non-functional Data**
>
> Data that isn't functional, that doesn't do a practical job, is more of an adornment to the system's software than a part of it. Thus, we don't insist on the free license criteria for non-functional data. It can be included in a free system distribution as long as its license gives you permission to copy and redistribute, both for commercial and non-commercial purposes. For example, some game engines released under the GNU GPL have accompanying game information—a fictional world map, game graphics, and so on—released under such a verbatim-distribution license. This kind of data can be part of a free system distribution, even though its license does not qualify as free, because it is non-functional.

Please note that this quote applies to free distributions in general and is not an authoritative interpretation of the GPL.

For the source code of your application, I recommend you simply use the GPL v3 if there are no compelling reasons no to. Using this license puts you on the safe side and makes it easier for your project and the ones it interacts with to mutually benefit from each other.

If this is an option, dual-licensing the pictures under the GPL and a more permissive license (maybe some *Creative Commons* variant) could be useful too. Note that you may always impose less restrictions on the parts that you added – may it be data or code – as long as you also grant the rights spelled out in the GPL.

Comment: One question there though. If I understand it correctly what you are saying then the script itself is non essential data as long as it has no functionality, but if the script contains decisions that the player can make where he gets increases in his points or decreases, then it would be still non essential code if replacing the script by a different script that increases/decreases points can be done without problems?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I understand enough about games to give a reliable answer here but if the “script” is more a work of art than programming, then I think it would fall under the “data” category.

Comment: That is no problem. Btw accepted your answer as it is an answer to my uestion and that one point is only a minor one (which is quite difficult to define anyway)  tnx